# EF code first using specific project on solution with ignoring migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, db-first

I have a solution and it has many projects. My solution look like below:

MySolution

- WinService1
- WinService2
- WebUI
- Entities
- DataAccessLayer
- BusinessLogic

My Winservice1 and WinService2 projects used DAL. My problem is here. If somebody change entity and update database for WebUI project, I need to update my Windows services on the remote. But I don't want to update because their entities are specific and if they will change, this mean I have to update.

My question on here. Could I use a db-first database? Or is it possible to ignore (not check) migrations on specific projects? What's the best practices?

Comment: You could [set the initializer to null](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but how can I configure that for only WinService1? I use unitofwork and repository. They are common for solution.

Comment: Use a null initializer for everything. You can still invoke migrations when needed.